# apex:commandButton align center

Tags: visualforce, commandbutton

How to move Button 'Create Referral' to center. I don't want that button on new Line. I want to show both Ok and Create Referral on same line,
Ok on left side and 'Create Referral' to center

```
<apex:commandButton value="Ok" oncomplete="javascript:CloseAndRefresh()" />

<apex:commandButton value="Create Referral" action="{!CreateRefferal}"/>
```

How to do that ?

Comment: Your question is unclear, possibly posting an image would help members to understand. Secondly from where you are trying to access Create Referral button?

Comment: apex:commandButton value="Ok" oncomplete="javascript:CloseAndRefresh()"
apex:commandButton value="Create Referral" action="{!CreateRefferal}"

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap those buttons inside `apex:pageBlockButtons` as follows

```
<apex:pageBlock title="My Content" mode="edit">
    <apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:commandButton value="Ok" oncomplete="javascript:CloseAndRefresh()" />

        <apex:commandButton value="Create Referral" action="{!CreateRefferal}"/> 
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

For more information, refer [apex:pageBlockButtons](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockButtons.htm)